# Biber won't generate Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I am trying to switch over to BibLaTeX from BibTeX.  When I use `backend=bibtex` I get the proper citations and bibliography (but also the limitations of BibTeX).  When I change to `backend=biber` (and change the BibTeX engine to Biber in the preferences of TexShop), the citations all simply print a bold-face citation key and there is no bibliography.

Here is what I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{.../bibliography}


This is a sample sentence \cite{Railton1984}.

\printbibliography
```

What I get is:

> This is a sample sentence **Railton1984**.

Rather than:

> This is a sample sentence (Railton 1984).

And no bibliography is printed.

Edit.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{test-bib.bib}


\begin{document}

This is my test document.  Railton says, ``bla bla bla''  \parencite[p. x]{Railton1984}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This works fine. I run (Latex --> Bibtex --> Latex --> Latex), and I get the expected output.  When I change the biblatex argument to backend=biber, and run Latex --> Biber --> Latex --> Latex (I changed the Preferenes in TexShop to make sure the Bibtex engine runs biber and not bibtex), I get an error.

When I run Latex I get the error

> " 'short-test.bbl' is wrong format version expected 2.3"

When I run biber I get the error

> "Data source not found in..."

In case it matters, here is the bibliography file I am using, which has just one entry:

```
@article{Railton1984,  
  author = {Railton, Peter},  
title = {Alienation, Consequentialism, and the Demands of Morality},  
journal = {Philosophy and Public Affairs},  
volume = {13},  
number = {2},  
pages = {134-171},  
year = {1984}  
}
```

Comment: Did you actually run `biber` after compiling your document, and then compile your document again? That is, `pdflatex` (or whatever) -> `biber` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`.

Comment: `\addbibresource` does not expect a path. It expects a file name, complete with extension - `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`. Put the file somewhere TeX can find it (e.g. in the same directory as your `.tex` file or in your personal `texmf` tree) so that you don't need the path, and don't forget the extension.

Comment: Please post a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior under with backend=biber and works correctly with backend=bibtex.

Comment: @cfr I believe `\addbibresource` *does* allow paths; but it requires the `.bib` extension, differently from `\bibliography`. Also `.../bibliography` is not a valid path under most systems.

Comment: The `bbl` generated by bibtex is not compatible when you use  `biber`. You can remove it. Also, you might consider to upgrade to the last version of `biblatex/biber`. The newest one use version 2.4 of the `bbl` format.

Comment: Did you delete the `.bbl` as Guido suggested and then try the compilation sequence again?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the .bbl (along with everything else excecpt the original .tex and .bib files) between running the bibtex and biber.  Still get the "Data not found in" error when I run biber, and when I run LaTeX, I'm back to the original problem, where it just prints a bolded version of the bibliography key (In this case **Railton1984**).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not entirely clear what caused the problem (very probably a mismatch of Biber and `biblatex`, in which case an update resolves all issues) with the information at hand. Since the question has not really been picked up on, I vote to close.